# how could i group subtracted counts?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have Orderdetails table which contains orders details , i need to count sales for each product subtracted by refunded(returned) orders for each produc.

```
ex: total sales of product = sales orders total - returned orders of a product
```

Note : i used transaction type field so that i could filter order type.

Order details table fields.

```
ID - Productname - Price - ono - transaction_type
11 - prod1       - 100.00- 1   - salesorder
12 - prod2       - 200.00- 2   - salesorder
13 - prod1       - 100.00- 1   - returned
14 - prod2       - 200.00- 3   - salesorder
15 - prod2       - 200.00- 4   - salesorder
```

What i ask for

```
Productname - Total sales
Prod1       - 0
Prod2       - 3
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/914a5/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this---

```
Select Product_NAME, Sum(Case when transaction_type='salesorder' then 1 Else 0 End)- Sum(Case when transaction_type!='salesorder' then 1 Else 0 End) as TotalSale
from OrderDetals group by Product_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks so much it a genius idea :)

Comment: @ZiadELNaggar not genius , yeah you can say tricky one... glad that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
SELECT ProductName, 
SUM(CASE WHEN [transaction_type] = 'salesorder' THEN [Quentity] ELSE -1 * [Quentity] END) AS [Total Number Of Sale]
FROM your_table)name
GROUP BY ProductName
```